# Android:Assign image bottom of button programatically

Tags: android, image, button

I am trying to set image to button at bottom programatically. I create show more button in java code and want to assign arrow image at the bottom of button but didn't find method which assign image programartically.
Here is my button code.

```
    btnAddHotel = new Button(this);
    btnAddHotel.setText("show more");
    btnAddHotel.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    btnAddHotel.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    btnAddHotel.setTypeface(faceNormal);
    btnAddHotel.setTextSize(12);
```

Please give me any reference method which assign image at the bottom of button.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean the Java equivalent of the XML attribute `android:drawableBottom="@drawable/...."`?

Comment: yes.... i want java code equivalent  to xml attribute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()`. The constructor is:

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

And for the positions you do not wish to assign an Image resource to, you just put a **0** in their place. For example:

```
btnAddHotel.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, R.drawable.some_image_resource);
```

Read more about [`setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

**EDIT:** Because the Android `Button` inherits attributes from the `TextView` widget, the above link pointing to the `TextView` documentation is still a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question correctly you can use `setBackgroundDrawable()` on your button:

```
btnAddHotel.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.xxx);
```